# A question about declaring a friend template function in a template class(C++)

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I'm writing my assignment that implements some functions of matrix. Here is a simplified version in order to fix on the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class CMyMatrix{
private:
    int row;
    int col;
    T** elements;
public:
    CMyMatrix(int row, int col);
    void SetMatrix(T* data, int row, int col);
    friend void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<T> matrix);
};

template<class T>
CMyMatrix<T>::CMyMatrix(int row,int col) {
    this->row = row;
    this->col = col;
    this->elements = new T* [row];
    for (int i = 0;i < row;i++) {
        this->elements[i] = new T[col];
    }
}

template<class T>
void CMyMatrix<T>::SetMatrix(T* data, int row, int col) {
    this->row = row;
    this->col = col;
    if (elements != 0) delete[]elements;
    this->elements = new T* [row];
    for (int i = 0;i < row;i++) {
        this->elements[i] = new T[col];
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < row * col;i++) {
        elements[i / col][i % col] = data[i];
    }
}


template<class T>
void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<T> matrix) {
    for (int i = 0;i < matrix.row;i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < matrix.col;j++) {
            cout << matrix.elements[i][j] << " ";
            if (j == matrix.col - 1) {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    CMyMatrix<int> matrix(2, 3); 
    int a[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    matrix.SetMatrix(a, 2, 3);
    DisplayMatrix(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Our teacher said we have to make "DisplayMatrix" a global function so it has to be a friend function of class CMyMatrix(If I don't want to write more functions). But there is an exception like this.
Code: LNK2019;    Description: unresolved external symbol "void _cdecl DisplayMatrix(class CMyMatrix)"(?DisplayMatrix@@YAXV?$CMyMatrix@H@@@Z) referenced in function _main;    Line 1; 
File:CMyMatrix.obj

I notice that the "DisplayMatrix" in class CMyMatrix don't change color in my IDE, so I think there might  be some problems. But I don't know how to solve it. I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `friend` declaration declares a non-template function, which doesn't match the function template's definition in the global scope.

You could

```
// forward declaration
template<class T>
class CMyMatrix;

// declaration
template<class T>
void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<T> matrix);

template<class T>
class CMyMatrix{
private:
    int row;
    int col;
    T** elements;
public:
    CMyMatrix(int row, int col);
    void SetMatrix(T* data, int row, int col);
    // friend declaration; refering to the function template
    friend void DisplayMatrix<T>(CMyMatrix<T> matrix);
    //                       ^^^
};

...

// definition
template<class T>
void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<T> matrix) {
    for (int i = 0;i < matrix.row;i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < matrix.col;j++) {
            cout << matrix.elements[i][j] << " ";
            if (j == matrix.col - 1) {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or declare template `friend` as

```
template<class T>
class CMyMatrix{
private:
    int row;
    int col;
    T** elements;
public:
    CMyMatrix(int row, int col);
    void SetMatrix(T* data, int row, int col);
    // declares template friend;
    // note that all the instantiations of DisplayMatrix become friend
    template <class X>
    friend void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<X> matrix);
};

...

template<class T>
void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<T> matrix) {
    for (int i = 0;i < matrix.row;i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < matrix.col;j++) {
            cout << matrix.elements[i][j] << " ";
            if (j == matrix.col - 1) {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But why `SetMatrix` don't need a `<T>`?

Comment: @BlackieMia Because it's a **non-template** (member function).

Comment: But there is a `T` in the parameter list, isn't it a template function?

Comment: @BlackieMia No, `T` is the template parameter of the class `CMyMatrix`, which is a class template. So `SetMatrix` is a non-template member function of class template `CMyMatrix`.

Comment: Another alternative is to define the friend (non template) method inline (inside the class).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present an answer that is not really a solution. The point of this non-solution is to expand upon why [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61170587) works (I admit that this answer would be worth little without the answer provided by songyuanyao.) This might help clarify things for future readers, especially if certain comments ever disappear.

To start, here is a simplified setup, where I've removed some things extraneous to the question (c.f. [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)):

```
template<class T>
class CMyMatrix{
    friend void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<T>);
};

template<class T>
void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<T>) {
}

int main(){
    CMyMatrix<int> matrix;
    DisplayMatrix(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the `friend` is declared as a (non-template) function, while the definition of `DisplayMatrix` is a function template. These do not match, so the compiler is left with two meanings for the identifier `DisplayMatrix`. When figuring out which meaning to use for the line `DisplayMatrix(matrix);`, the compiler prefers the non-template (which is declared, but never defined).

So the answer is to make your declaration and definition agree. One way to do this – likely not the solution anyone is looking for, but a way to make the compiler happy – is to change the definition to no longer be a template.

```
void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<int>) {
}
```

With this change, the code compiles. Well, it complies provided you stick to `int` as your template parameter. So not really a solution, but a demonstration of what the `friend` declaration actually declares. The real solution is to keep the (template) definition of `DisplayMatrix` and adjust the `friend` declaration, as in the accepted answer.

---

It might be interesting to note that gcc (but apparently not clang?) has a warning applicable to this situation.

> ```
> warning: friend declaration 'void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<T>)' declares a
>          non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>      friend void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<T> matrix);
>                                                   ^
> note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template
>       has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
> ```

Comment: Since the `friend` declaration is a non-template function, what does the compiler think the `T` in the parameter is?

Comment: @BlackieMia The `T` is bound the same as every other instance of `T` in the definition of `CMyMatrix`. If you had instead declared `template<class Noodles> class CMyMatrix`, then the `friend` declaration would become `friend void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<Noodles>);`. When you instantiate `CMyMatrix<int>`, the friend function is `void DisplayMatrix(CMyMatrix<int>)`, as seen in this answer.